# Rails: Change class of div generated by fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails keeps wrapping the form inputs generated by `fields_for` (nested attributes) with a `<div class="fields">...</div>`. I need to change the class to "col-md-4" or at least add to it. How would I do this?

```
<%= form.fields_for :products_colors do |pc| %>
    <%= render 'products_color', :pc => pc %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

```
fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

You can add `class` to `options`, like this :

```
fields_for(:products_color, nil, { :class => 'col-md-4' }) do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding wrapper: :false did the trick.

```
form.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: 'new_record', :wrapper => false )
```